# A series involving the harmonic numbers : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Let $H_{n}$ be the *n*th harmonic number defined by $ H_{n} := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$.

How would you prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}=\frac{\pi^4}{72}?$$

---

Simply replacing $H_{n}$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ does not seem like a good starting point. Perhaps another representation of the *n*th harmonic number would be more useful.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119253/interesting-square-of-log-sin-integral/120428#120428) for another answer to this question; it's a little roundabout, but it only requires basic complex analysis.

Answer (score 43):

The Euler sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^{q}}$, where $q$ is an odd positive integer greater than $1$, can also be evaluated using this approach. [See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1358965/16033)

---

Using the integration representation $$H_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-t^{n}}{1-t} \, dt \ ,$$

we have

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^{3}} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-t^{n}}{1-t} \ dt \\  &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-t} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-t^{n}}{n^{3}} \\ &=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\zeta(3) - \text{Li}_{3}(t)}{1-t} \ dt \tag{1} \\ &=- \Big(\zeta(3)-\text{Li}_{3}(t)\Big) \ln(1-t) \Bigg|_{0}^{1}  - \int^{1}_{0} \frac{ \text{Li}_{2}(t) \log(1-t)}{t} \ dt \\ &= -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \text{Li}_{2}(t) \log(1-t)}{t} \ dt \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \text{Li}_{2}(t) \, d \big(\text{Li}_{2}(t)\big) \\ &= \frac{\big(\text{Li}_{2}(t)\big)^{2}}{2} \Bigg|^{1}_{0} \\ &= \frac{\zeta^{2}(2)}{2} \\ &= \frac{\pi^{4}}{72}. \end{align}$$

$ $

$(1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Comment: How do you justify swapping the sum and integral on line 2?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{1-t^{n}}{n^{3} (1-t)}$ is nonnegative for all $t$ and all $n$

Answer (score 20):

I will try to reduce the sum to an integral:
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \frac{1}{\Gamma(3)} \int_0^\infty x^2 \mathrm{e}^{-n x} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty x^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \mathrm{e}^{-n x} \mathrm{d} x \tag{1}
$$
We now make use of the following generating function:
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n z^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \Delta_n \left(\frac{z^n}{z-1} \right)
$$
where $\Delta_n f_n = f_{n+1}-f_n$. We can now use summation by parts:
$$
     \sum_{n=1}^m a_n \Delta_n b_n = b_{m+1} a_m - b_1 a_1 - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} b_{n+1} \Delta_n a_n
$$
with $b_n = \frac{z^n}{z-1}$ and $a_n = H_n$, and using $\Delta_n H_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$, we get
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n z^n =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \Delta_n \left(\frac{z^n}{z-1} \right) = -1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n+1}}{z-1} \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{\log(1-z)}{z-1}
\tag{2} $$
Now, using $(2)$ in $(1)$:
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3} = -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty x^2 \frac{\log\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right)}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}} \mathrm{d}x \stackrel{t=\exp(-x)}{=} -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-t)}{1-t} \frac{\log^2(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t \tag{3}
$$ 
The latter integral can be evaluated using derivatives of the Euler beta function:
$$
   \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-t)}{1-t} \frac{\log^2(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t = \lim_{\alpha \downarrow 0} \lim_{\beta \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \alpha} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} \beta^2} \int_0^1 \left(1-t\right)^{\alpha-1} t^{\beta-1} \mathrm{d} t = \lim_{\alpha \downarrow 0} \lim_{\beta \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \alpha} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} \beta^2}  \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}
$$
Using 
$$
  \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)} = \left(\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} \right) \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1) \Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta+1)} = \left(\frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{1}{\beta} \right)  \left( 1 - \frac{\pi^2}{6} \alpha \beta + \left(\alpha \beta^2 + \beta \alpha^2\right) \zeta(3) - \frac{\pi^4}{360} \left(4 \alpha \beta^3 + \alpha^2 \beta^2 + 4 \alpha^3 \beta\right) + \cdots \right)
$$
Differentiating we get the result:
$$
    \lim_{\alpha \downarrow 0} \lim_{\beta \downarrow 0} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \alpha} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} \beta^2}  \frac{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)} = -\frac{\pi^2}{36}
$$
yielding with eq. $(3)$:
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3} = \frac{\pi^4}{72}
$$

Comment: How do you justify swapping the sum and integral in (1)?

Comment: @PeterM I guess [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem) will do

Answer (score 17):

Apparently [Euler showed in 1775](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/docs/originals/E477.pdf) that:
$$2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^q} = (q+2)\zeta(q+1)-
\sum_{m=1}^{q-2}\zeta(m+1)\zeta(q-m)$$
In your case, $q=3$, so that:
$$2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3} = 5\zeta(4)-
\zeta(2)^2 = 5\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^4}{36}=\frac{\pi^4}{36}$$
The original proof of euler's in english can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maa.org%2Feditorial%2Feuler%2Fhow%2520euler%2520did%2520it%252051%2520multizeta%2520functions.pdf&ei=f5UfUeDHJ-Pl4QSam4DYAw&usg=AFQjCNGBGgSGsdKWXUsiU2v2JQsxmEuykw&sig2=bJyKxFpL5qEeKqrNY80ibg&bvm=bv.42553238,d.bGE).

Comment: The final link is dead now.

Comment: Another closed form of the above sum is investigated at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq).

Answer (score 16):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n^{3}} = {\pi^{4} \over 72}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n^{3}}}
> &=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}\
> \overbrace{\quad\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over k} - {1 \over k + n}}\quad}
> ^{\ds{=\ H_{n}}}\ =\ 
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}k\pars{k + n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
> \bracks{{1 \over n^{2}k\pars{k + n}} + {1 \over k^{2}n\pars{n + k}}}
> =\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
> {k + n \over n^{2}k^{2}\pars{k + n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}k^{2}}
> =\half\pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}}^{2}
> =\half\pars{\pi^{2} \over 6}^{2}=\color{#66f}{\Large{\pi^{4} \over 72}}
> \approx 1.3529
> \end{align}

Comment: Nice answer. +1 I also liked your evaluation of that bino-harmonic sum. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815103/harmonic-numbers-series-i/875411#875411 Your approach to that sum simplified the evaluation considerably.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks. $H_{\rm n}$ is somehow tricky.

Comment: Very slick. I am impressed by this direct approach through series manipulation.

Answer (score 12):

Appealing to the integral identity I introduced in a [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/276590#276590) for the more general case of your sum

> $$ B(p,q) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k^{(p)}}{k^q}=\frac{(-1)^q}{\Gamma(q)}\int_{0}^{1}\!{\frac {\left(\ln\left(u\right)\right)^{q-1}{Li_{p}(u)} }{ u\left( u-1 \right)}}{du}, $$

where $Li_{p}(u)$ is the [polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), we can have the following integral representation for the sum

$$B(1,3) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_k}{k^3}=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(3)}\int_{0}^{1}\!{\frac {\ln^2\left(u\right){\ln(1-u)} }{ u\left( 1-u \right)}}{du} $$

$$ = -\frac{1}{\Gamma(3)}\lim_{w\to 0}\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{d}{dw} \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\int_{0}^{1} u^{s-1}\, (1-u)^{w-1} $$

$$ = -\frac{1}{2}\lim_{w\to 0}\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{d}{dw} \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\beta(s, w)=\frac{\pi^4}{72}, $$

where $\beta(s,w)=\frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(w)}{\Gamma(s+w)}$ is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

**Note:** $$ Li_{1}(x) = -\ln(1-x). $$

Answer (score 0):

We proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3363990)

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{k^n}=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}(-1)^{i-1}\zeta(n-i)\zeta(i+1),\quad n=3,5,7, ...$$

Set $n=3$ we get $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k}{k^3}=\frac54\zeta(4)$$

where $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$