# Gaussian Matrix Integral

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, measure-theory, definite-integrals

I need your help to solve this exercise :

Let $S$ be a symmetric Hermitian matrix $N\times N$ : $S=(s_{ij})$ with $s_{ij}=s_{ji}$.

1. When $\langle s_{ij}s_{kl}\rangle\neq 0$
2. What $$\int Tr(S^{2n})\;d\mu(s)$$ counts?
3. Calculate the moments of the matrix trace given by $$
   \int Tr(S^2) dS,\quad \int Tr(S^4) dS
   $$
   where S is a real symmetric matrix satisfying $S_{ij}=S_{ji}$.

We are supposed to use The Wick Theorem to solve it.

any idea on how to calculate this, thank you.

Comment: You need to fill in more details.

Comment: Why are you replacing the Hermitian matrix? What Hermitian matrix?  Could you add some context?  Is the first item a part of the formulation (like "Replace... $s_{ij}=s_{ji}$"... or is it a question?)

Comment: It's a part of formulation. I wrote the exercise as I received it.

Comment: Here is a link to Hermitian matrix

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix

Comment: Here some links for the Wick's theorem :
[link](http://qessence.eu/attachments/article/74/HubenerWicksTheoremForMatrixProductStates.pdf)
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem)
[link](http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys7240/phys7240_fa12/notes/Week8.pdf)

Comment: I changed $<a,b>$ to $\langle a,b\rangle$. That is standard.

Comment: @Daniel88 Also, small comment: a hermitian matrix is a symmetric one.  It is just "complex" symmetric.  All real symmetric matrices are hermitian but not all hermitian matrices are real symmetric.

Comment: @Integrals thanks I see What you mean :-)

Comment: Joining the party a bit late. I was just working on something like this. Woot! woot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question, you are really asking about the moments of the matrix trace for a Gaussian distribution.  This gives you the resolvent operator for Wigner's semi circle distribution.  Now what you want to solve in a gaussian matrix integral very common in probability/statistics/ random matrix theory
$$
\int Tr(H^{2p}) \exp\big[{-\frac{1}{2} H^{2}}\big] dH,\qquad p\in \mathbb{R}
$$ 
which has a beautiful result given by the Catalan Numbers!  Note,
$$
H_{ij}=H^\dagger_{ij},
$$
or in words, H is hermitian and $H\equiv S $ for your notation sake.  Also note to answer your question two, only even moments contribute to the integral which is why the exponent in the trace is given by 2p.  Odd moments vanish due to Gaussian symmetry.  I will calculate both 
$$
\langle Tr(H^2)\rangle,\quad \langle Tr(H^4)\rangle,\quad \langle Tr(H^{2n})\rangle
$$
where $\langle ...\rangle$ 
$$
\langle Tr(H^{2n})\rangle = \int dH \, Tr({H^{2n}}) e^{-\frac{1}{2}H^2}
$$ The integrand is invariant under unitary/orthogonal transformations  depending on if H is hermitian or real symmetric. Sowe see the integral can be reduced to an integral over the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_N$ of $H$.

ALSO: here are many proofs of this question on the web for you (if you do not like or believe mine):
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~mulase/texfiles/fukaya.pdf,

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-238-geometry-and-quantum-field-theory-fall-2002/lecture-notes/sec4.pdf

http://www.supelec.fr/d2ri/flexibleradio/cours/random-matrix-1.pdf (easier proof of matrix trace moments)

http://www.physik.uni-bielefeld.de/bibos/old-bibos-site/01-03-035.pdf

I will now derive the resolvent of the 
spectrum obtained.  Recall the resolvent is defined as 
\begin{equation}
G(z)=\frac{1}{N}\mathrm{Tr}\frac{1}{z-H}
\end{equation}
where H = H$^\top$.  We can expand the argument in the trace in powers of 1/z by
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{z-H}=\frac{1}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{H}{z}}
\end{equation}
and using the geometric series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^n= \frac{1}{1-z} \ \ \forall \ |\mathrm{z}| < 1,
\end{equation}
we can express
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{H}{z}}=\frac{1}{z}(1+\frac{H}{z} + 
 \big(\frac{H}{z}\big)^2 + O(n))= \frac{1}{z}+\frac{H}{z^2} + \frac{H^2}{z^3} + 
 \frac{1}{z}O(n).
\end{equation}
Putting this expression now back into G(z) we obtain
\begin{equation}
G(z)=\frac{1}{N\cdot z} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{Tr}\big(\frac{H}{z}\big)^k,
\end{equation}
if we take the average of this quantity
\begin{equation}
 \langle G(z) \rangle = \frac{1}{N\cdot z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \langle 
 \mathrm{Tr}\big(\frac{H}{z}\big)^k\rangle =\frac{1}{N\cdot z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty 
 z^{-k}\langle Tr(H^k) \rangle.
\end{equation}
However, it is clear from the spectrum that the distribution is an even 
function, so the odd moments must vanish, re-writing the average resolvent as
\begin{equation}
\langle G(z)\rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{-(2k+1)}\langle 
Tr(H^{2k})\rangle.
\end{equation}
We can see that the average resolvent is dependent on the moments of the 
distribution.  If we can calculate the moments (which is what you ask), the average resolvent is trivial 
from there.

I will now calculate the moments for the matrix trace weighted 
against the probability distribution for the Gaussian case
\begin{equation}
\langle Tr(H^{2k})\rangle=\int Tr(H^{2k})\cdot 
e^{-\frac{1}{2}Tr(H^2)}\mathrm{dH},
\end{equation}
where the integration is over the space of N x N real symmetric matrices.  The problem of calculating higher order moments arises naturally in probability theory and a common example is the higher order moments of the Gaussian distribution which are given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2k}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=(2k-1)!!
\end{equation}
This result is easily shown by using the partial integration method.  However the trace moments can be computed a number of different ways, we can use the Jacobian for gaussian random matrix models which is given by $\mathcal{J}\propto|\lambda_l-\lambda_k|^\beta$ where $\lambda$ is eigenvalues and $\beta=1,2,4$ for orthogonal, unitary, symplectic ensembles respectively.  So by a change of variables to eigenvalues, you can have an integral you can attempt to solve.  ${\it{However\ you\ want\ to\ use\ Wick's}}$. 
Calculating the second moment of the distribution
\begin{equation}
\langle Tr(H^{2})\rangle=\langle \sum_{i,j=1}H_{ij}H_{ji}\rangle, \qquad (\text{answer to c})
\end{equation}
explicitly we can contract indices and write the average as 
\begin{eqnarray}
H_{ij}H_{ji} =N^2, \qquad (\text{answer to  c})
\end{eqnarray}
This case was trivial since we only had one two free indices.  For higher order moments, we need to evaluate each contraction more carefully.  When contractions intersect a summation index is lost, and for large N only the non-intersecting contractions contribute.  There can only be $N^V$ combinations of indices, where V is the number of free indices.  So by summing over all contractions and determining the contribution of each, we can get the desired result.  Using these rules we can calculate
\begin{equation}
\langle Tr(H^{4})\rangle=\langle H_{ij}H_{jk}\rangle \langle H_{kl}H_{li}\rangle + \langle H_{ij} H_{kl}\rangle \langle H_{jk}H_{li}\rangle + \langle H_{ij}H_{li}\rangle \langle H_{jk} H_{kl} \rangle 
\end{equation}
where a contraction is defined by 
\begin{equation}
\langle H_{ij}H_{kl}\rangle=\delta_{il} \delta_{jk}.
\end{equation}
Using this result and contracting indices we can write 
\begin{equation}
\langle Tr(H^{4})\rangle=\sum_{i,j,k,l} (\delta_{ik}\delta_{jj}\delta_{ki}\delta_{ll}+\delta_{il}\delta_{kj}\delta_{ji}\delta_{lk}+\delta_{ii}\delta_{jl}\delta_{lj}\delta_{kk})=2N^3+N,\qquad (\text{answer  to  c})
\end{equation}
since one of the contractions only has one free index it contributes N.  The other two contractions both contribute N$^3$.  The 6th moment of the distribution has 15 possibilities to contract so I will omit this derivation.  In general, the nth moment is written by expanding the product as
\begin{equation}
\langle Tr(H^{2k})\rangle= \sum_{i_1,i_2,...i_{2k}}H_{i_1 i_2} H_{i_2 i_3}...H_{i_{2k}i_1}=\frac{1}{k+1}\binom {2k} {k}=C_k \qquad (\text{general answer to A,B,C})
\end{equation}
where C$_{k}$ is the Catalan numbers which represents the k different ways to match the entries.  This result can be plugged into the average resolvent expression and summed to give
\begin{equation}
\langle G(z)\rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{-(2k+1)}\langle 
Tr(H^{2k})\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\big(z-\sqrt{z^2+4}\big).
\end{equation}
This equality is obtained by using contractions and expanding the average resolvent for large z as done above \begin{equation}
\langle G(z) \rangle=\bigg\langle \frac{1}{N} \big(z^{-1}+z^{-2}TrH+z^{-3}Tr H^2 +z^{-4} Tr H^3 + O(N)\big )\bigg \rangle.
\end{equation}
Since the odd moments vanish due to symmetry, the even moments are calculated as shown above.  We obtain
\begin{equation}
\langle G(z) \rangle= z^{-1}+z^{-1}\langle G(z) \rangle ^2
\end{equation}
which can be solved for G(z) by using the quadratic equation
\begin{equation}
\langle G(z) \rangle =\frac{1}{2}\big(z-\sqrt{z^2+4}\big) 
\end{equation}
which is the expression above.  Asymptotically at large z,  $G(z)  \sim \frac{1}{z}$.
This result can be plugged into 
$$
\begin{equation}
\langle \rho(\lambda)\rangle = - \lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{N}{\pi}\Im{\langle G(\lambda +i \epsilon) }\rangle.
\end{equation}
$$ to calculate the spectral density.  We can do this by writing the average resolvent in terms of eigenvalues and use imaginary increments.  However the resolvent has a branch cut structure in the complex plane since it behaves as $1/z$ for large z.

This cut structure is a simple pole and this is why we use imaginary increments.  We need to write the average resolvent for each sides of the pole, so
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle G(\lambda +i\epsilon)\rangle= \frac{1}{2}\big(\lambda+i\epsilon -\sqrt{(\lambda+i\epsilon)^2-4}\big)\\
\langle G(\lambda -i\epsilon)\rangle= \frac{1}{2}\big(\lambda-i\epsilon -\sqrt{(\lambda-i\epsilon)^2-4}\big).
\end{eqnarray}
We can now invert this relation to obtain the spectral density
\begin{equation}
\rho(\lambda)= \frac{N}{2\pi}\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\Im \big[ \sqrt{(\lambda+i\epsilon)^2-4}-(-\sqrt{(\lambda-i\epsilon)^2-4}) \big]
\end{equation}
which can be simplified to yield 
\begin{equation}
\rho(\lambda)=\frac{N}{\pi}\sqrt{\lambda^2-4}
\end{equation}
which is Wigner's semi-circle.

EDIT: since you again asked me about how to calculate average quantities (they are in the post above), he is an alternative method for you. (answer  to  a)

Formally we can calculate the correlation function by using
\begin{equation}
\big<x_i x_j\big>=\frac{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^N dx_i \, x_i x_j \exp\big(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^{N} x_i H_{ij}x_j\big)    }{   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^N dx_i \exp\big(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^{N} x_i H_{ij}x_j\big)   }.
\end{equation}
First, I will give a general proof for the expectation value of
\begin{equation}
\big<x_i f(x)\big>=C^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^Nx\, x_i f(x) \exp\big( -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j,k=1}^{N} x_j H_{jk} x_k  \big).
\end{equation}
We can now use the identity
$$
x_i \exp\big( -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j,k=1}^{N} x_j H_{jk} x_k  \big)=-\sum_l H^{-1}_{il}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l} \exp\big( -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j,k=1}^{N} x_j H_{jk} x_k, \big)
$$
inserting this into the equation above and using integration by parts we obtain
$$
\big<x_i f(x)\big>= C^{-1} \sum_l H^{-1}_{il} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d^Nx \exp\big( -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j,k=1}^{N} x_j H_{jk} x_k  \big) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_l}.
$$
We can write this more compactly as
\begin{equation}
\big<x_i f(x)\big>=\sum_l \big<x_i x_l\big> \bigg<\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_l}\bigg>.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying to understand all the details because honestly I have not yet fully understood.

Comment: could you give an answer to Question 3 ?

Comment: Also note:  This has to do with "Random Matrix Theory", "Gaussian Matrix Integrals", "Wigner's Semi-circle Law", " Matrix Trace integral", so you can google things like this to help you.  For help in wick's theorem, see Tony Zee- QFT.

Comment: @Daniel88 I solved question 3 for you, its in there, just look! :) But here I will again,
$$
\langle Tr(H^2)\rangle=N^2,\quad \langle Tr(H^4)\rangle =2N^3+N,\quad Tr(H^{2k})=\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}
$$
which are the catalan numbers.  Note odd powers of the matrix trace moments vanish due to Gaussian symmetry.  Please read the details of the post though this is in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to understand each step. How can I send you private message ? I am new here and I don't know how to join you !

Comment: @Daniel88 Apparently, since you have a low reputation , you are not able to do a private chat.  In order to do so you will have to increase your reputation number.  Do you want to check my answer or up vote it?  Thanks. I up voted your question.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I am trying to vote by I can't do it ?!

Comment: @Daniel88 You need over 15 reputation.  But you have that!  Try again, it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14769/discussion-between-integrals-and-daniel88).

Comment: It took time for me to understand this answer. I don't just believe you answer kind of question meanwhile I always avoid matrix integral. Hahaha... +1 anyway for your effort.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thank you my friend :)  HaHa

Comment: I forgot one thing Jeff. I really like this notation $\langle ...\rangle\,$ to express expectation value instead of $\text{E}[...]$. It reminds me the time when I took quantum mechanics course. Such an elegant symbol.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Yes the inner product/expectation value is conveniently defined with this $\langle ... \rangle$ notation.  :)

Comment: @Integrals Could you please give me more details for Question 1 ?

Comment: @Daniel88 i added more to the bottom of the post in regards to details for number 1.  also note: proof of number 1 was already in the post.  The idea is (as said above) :When contractions intersect a summation index is lost, and for large N only the non-intersecting contractions contribute. There can only be $N^V$ combinations of indices, where V is the number of free indices. So by summing over all contractions and determining the contribution of each, we can get the desired result.

Comment: @Integrals thanks. As I am trying to undrestand step by step. Could you juste like define clearly what is the answer to each question ? May be if you can put questions's numbers il will be helpful. Also for the first question i didn't see where is not equal to zero

Comment: @Daniel88 You need to think clearly about the questions and read the post clearly.  I explicitly now wrote next to answers which part it belongs to:  Note: the general answer to Part C is:$$
\langle Tr(H^{2k})\rangle= \sum_{i_1,i_2,...i_{2k}}H_{i_1 i_2} H_{i_2 i_3}...H_{i_{2k}i_1}=\frac{1}{k+1}\binom {2k} {k}=C_k$$.  The general answer to part A is: only the even moments of the matrix trace are non-zero.  All odd moments are zero.  Ex: $$\langle H_{ij}H_{kl}H_{mi}\rangle=0$$.  This also answers your question to part B, since only even moments contribute to this integral.

Comment: @Integrals I am really thankful for you

Comment: @Daniel88 No problem.  Basically part C is the whole problem.  Parts A,B are small parts that are easily realized by doing part C.

Comment: It's not an easy probelm. You are really good Jeff.

Comment: @Integrals Jeff is it possible for you to solve this:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810265/counting-meanders-on-n-points-with-a-gaussian-integral


It's also about Gaussian Integrals

Comment: @Daniel88 What are these questions for, what class are you taking?    I am unsure at the moment how to do deal with the other question.  You asked me yesterday , I didn't forget.  I will have to think about it.  I am not familiar with knots or meanders, if you have insight let me know.

Comment: @Integrals I am in Maths-Physics class. This about random matrix and integrals. Maths part is not my best

Comment: @Daniel88 My specialty is in random matrices, so if you have questions about this feel free to post.  I will try to solve the Gaussian Meander problem, however it may take me a day or two.

Comment: @Integrals Yes please try. I will let you khow if i get more hints

Comment: @Daniel88 I may know what to do for that problem.  I will post the solution by tomorrow night

Comment: Nice answer Jeff (not that I understand it - but it looks nice!) and thank you for that resource you sent me the other day. 

Bennett.

Comment: @Integrals This is good news :-) looking forward to see it

Comment: @Integrals I send you an email can you please tell me if you get it ?

Comment: @Daniel88 yes check your e-mail.

Comment: @Integrals Yes ! answered too !