# Evaluation of two Euler type sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

We know that the harmonic number sum (also called Euler type sum) [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023022/sum-of-harmonic-numbers-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-n22nn2)
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{H_n^{\left( 2 \right)}}}{{{n^2}{2^n}}}}   = {\rm{L}}{{\rm{i}}_4}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)\; + \frac{1}{{16}}\zeta (4) + \frac{1}{4}\zeta (3)\log 2 - \frac{1}{4}\zeta \left( 2 \right){\log ^2}2 + \frac{1}{{24}}{\log ^4}2,$$
How to calculate the closed form of the following Euler type Sums
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{H_n^{\left( 2 \right)}}}{{{n^3}{2^n}}}} ,\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{H_n^{\left( 2 \right)}}}{{{n^4}{2^n}}}}.$$
Here the harmonic numbers are defined by
$$H^{(k)}_n:=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac {1}{j^k}\quad {\rm and}\quad H^{(k)}_0:=0.$$

Comment: In the following post you can find a closed form for $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{H_{n}^{\left(2\right)}}{n^{3}2^{n}}$. In the same post you may find the closed form of $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{H_{n}^{\left(2\right)}}{n^{3}}x^{n}$ so maybe integrating the formula it is possible to find a closed form for $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{H_{n}^{\left(2\right)}}{n^{4}2^{n}}.$ This is the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909228/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn32n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{H_n^{\left( 2 \right)}}}{{{n^3}{2^n}}}}+\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{H_n^{\left( 3 \right)}}}{{{n^2}{2^n}}}}=\frac{9}{16}\zeta_2\zeta_3 -\frac{9}{16}\zeta_3\ln^2 2 +\frac{1}{6}\zeta _2\ln^3 2  -\frac{29}{32}\zeta_5+\frac{1}{4}\zeta_4\ln2-\frac{1}{60}\ln^5 2+2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$  Relationship obtained after long calculations

Comment: @user178256 that relation that relates the two sums is amazing. I have another relation that related these two sums which means we can solve for them by elimination. my relation can be obtained very easily by the way. did you reply on many sums/ integrals to find this relation?

Answer (score 3):

By Cauchy product we have

$$\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(\frac{4H_n}{n^3}+\frac{2H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}-\frac{6}{n^4}\right)$$

divide both sides by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$ and use the fact that $\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}=\frac1{n2^n}$ we have

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}\left(\frac{4H_n}{n^3}+\frac{2H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}-\frac{6}{n^4}\right)$$

rearrange to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}=3\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^42^n}+\frac12\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx$$

Substitute [the first sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944065/find-the-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2nn4/3195117#3195117)

\begin{align}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^42^n}&=2\operatorname{Li_5}\left( \frac12\right)+\ln2\operatorname{Li_4}\left( \frac12\right)-\frac16\ln^32\zeta(2)
+\frac12\ln^22\zeta(3)\\
&\quad-\frac18\ln2\zeta(4)- 
\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac1{32}\zeta(5)+\frac1{40}\ln^52
\end{align}

along with [the result from Song's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325928)

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\right)^2}{x}\ dx=\frac12\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac78\ln^22\zeta(3)-\frac58\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac{27}{32}\zeta(5)+\frac78\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\-\frac{7}{60}\ln^52-2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)$$

we get

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}=-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-3\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{23}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac1{16}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac{23}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\-\frac{23}{16}\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac7{12}\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{13}{120}\ln^52$$