# How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Can we evaluate   $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}$ ?

where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n$ is the harmonic number.

A related integral is $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac x2\right)}{x}dx$.

where $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}$ is the dilogarithmic function.

---

Here is how the integral and the sum are related:

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263927/prove-frac-partial-partial-m-textbn-m-textbn-m-sum-k-0n-1-f/3271177#3271177) we have

$$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}$$

Divide both sides by $n^22^n$ then sum up we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^22^n}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x/2)}{x}dx$$

Comment: We can certainly evaluate it numerically. It's unlikely to have a closed form solution in terms of "nice" functions. Are you looking for a closed form solution?

Comment: Well, it is at least doable for $n^2$ instead of $n^3$ in the denominator (of course, only by considering $\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)$ as given as usual).

Comment: @parsiad yes solution should be in closed form.

Comment: @mrtaurho the $n^2$ version is already calculated and I posted the problem/ solution before.

Comment: @AliShather Ah, okay. I wasn't aware of this. However, I can't adapt my solution in order to evaluate this sum.

Comment: @I'll try it today. I'll send you the link of the $n^2$ version.

Comment: @mrtaurho here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256841/sum-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-n2n22n/3256860#3256860

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the generating function of $\displaystyle\{H_k^2\}_{k=1}^\infty$:
$$
\frac{\text{Li}_2(x) +\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k^2 x^k 
$$ we can observe that
\begin{align*}
S =&  \sum_{k=1}^\infty {H_k^2 \over 2^k} \frac 1{k^2}\\
=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty {H_k^2 \over 2^k} \frac 1 2\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\ln^2 x\ dx\\
=&\frac 1 2 \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k^2\left(\frac x 2\right)^k\right)\frac{\ln^2 x}{x} dx\\
=& \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k^2 x ^k\right)  \frac{\ln^2 (2x)}{x} dx \\
=& \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) +\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}  \frac{\ln^2 x}{x} dx \\
&+ \ln 2\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) +\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}  \frac{\ln x}{x} dx \\
&+\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) +\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x} \frac{dx}{x}\\
=&: I_1 + I_2 + I_3.
\end{align*}

---

For $I_1$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_1=&\frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 12 } \frac{\big[\text{Li}_2(x)+\ln^2(1-x)\big]\ln^2 x}{x(1-x)}dx \\
=& \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 12 } \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)\ln^2 x}{x}dx+\frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 12 } \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx +\frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\ln^2 (1-x)\ln^2 x}{x(1-x)} dx\\
=&:I_1'+I_1''+I_1'''.
\end{align*}

---

For $I_1'$, we integrate by parts twice to get
\begin{align*}
I_1' \underset{\text{IBP}}{=}& \frac 1 2\left[ \text{Li}_3(x)\ln^2 x\right]^{1/2}_0 -\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\frac{\text{Li}_3(x) \ln x}{x} dx\\
\underset{\text{IBP}}{=}&\frac{\ln^2 2\ \text{Li}_3(1/2)}2 - \left[\text{Li}_4(x)\ln x\right]^{1/2}_0 +\int_0^{\frac 1 2 }\frac{\text{Li}_4(x)}x dx\\
=&\frac{\ln^2 2\ \text{Li}_3(1/2)}2 + \ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)+\text{Li}_5(1/2)\\
=&\boxed{\text{Li}_5(1/2)+\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)+\frac{7\ln^2 2}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac {\pi^2\ln^3 2}{24}+\frac{\ln^5 2}{12}}
\end{align*} where the well-known value of
$
\text{Li}_3(1/2) = \frac 78 \zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{12}+\frac{\ln^3 2}{6}
$ is used to simplify.

---

For $I_1''$, by integrating by parts,
\begin{align*}
I_1'' \underset{\text{IBP}}{=}& \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} \ln(1-x)\left[\frac{2\ln x\text{Li}_2(x)}{x} - \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2 x}{x}\right]dx +\frac{\ln^3 2}{2}\text{Li}_2(1/2)\\
=&  {\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \ln x\frac{\ln(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x)}{x} dx}-\underbrace{\frac 1 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2}   \frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2 x}{x}dx}_{=:J} +\frac{\ln^3 2}{2}\text{Li}_2(1/2)\\
\underset{\text{IBP}}{=}&\frac{\ln 2}2\text{Li}_2^2(1/2) +{\frac 1 2\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\frac{\text{Li}_2^2(x)}{x} dx}-J +\frac{\ln^3 2}{2}\text{Li}_2(1/2)\\
=&\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{288} -\frac{\ln^5 2}{8}+{\frac 1 2\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\frac{\text{Li}_2^2(x)}{x} dx}-J.
\end{align*} 
The well-known value of $\text{Li}_2(1/2) = \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac{\ln^2 2}{2}$ is used to simplify. In fact, the integral ${\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\text{Li}_2^2(x)}{x} dx}$ was already evaluated in my previous answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305999/compute-int-01-2-frac-left-operatornameli-2x-right2x-dx/3325928#3325928):
\begin{align*}
 {\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\frac{\text{Li}_2^2(x)}{x} dx} = &-2\text{Li}_5(1/2) -2\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)+\frac{27}{32}\zeta(5) +\frac{7\pi^2}{48}\zeta(3)-\frac{7\ln^2 2}{8}\zeta(3) \\
&-\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{144} +\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{12} - \frac{7\ln^5 2}{60}. 
\end{align*}

---

For $J$, we make substitution $y= \frac{x}{1-x}$ to get
\begin{align*}
J=&\frac 1 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+y)\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{y(1+y)}dy\\
=&\frac 1 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+y)\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{y}dy-\frac 1 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+y)\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{1+y}dy\\
=&:K-L.
\end{align*}

---

For $K$, expanding $\ln^2\left(\frac y {1+y}\right)=\big[\ln y -\ln(1+y)\big]^2$ and integrating by parts we get
\begin{align*}
K =&\frac 1 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+y)\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{y}dy\\
=& \frac 12{ \int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 y\ln^2(1+y)}{y} dy}-{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y\ln^3(1+y)}{y} dy}+\frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}{y}dy\\
\underset{\text{IBP}}{=}&-\frac 1 3 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 y \ln(1+y)}{1+y}dy + \frac 3 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 y\ln^2(1+y)}{1+y}dy +\frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}{y}dy
\end{align*} Doing the same thing for $L$,
\begin{align*}
L = & \frac 1 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+y)\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}{1+y}dy\\
=& \frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 y\ln^2(1+y)}{1+y}dy- {\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y\ln^3(1+y)}{1+y} dy} +\frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}{1+y} dy\\
\underset{\text{IBP}}{=}& \frac 12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 y\ln^2(1+y)}{1+y}dy+\frac 1 4 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}y dy +\frac{\ln^5 2}{10}.
\end{align*} This gives that
\begin{align*}
J=&K-L\\
=&-\frac 1 3 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 y \ln(1+y)}{1+y}dy + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 y\ln^2(1+y)}{1+y}dy +\frac 14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}{y}dy -\frac{\ln^5 2}{10}\\
=&:-V_1+V_2+V_3 -\frac{\ln^5 2}{10}.
\end{align*}

---

For $V_1$, we can use the Maclaurin series of $\frac{\ln (1+y)}{1+y} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} H_k y^k$ to get
\begin{align*}
V_1=&\frac 1 3\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 y\ln(1+y)}{1+y} dy \\
=& \frac 1 3\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}H_k {\int_0^1 y^k\ln^3 y\ dy} \\
=& \frac{-6}{3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}H_k}{(k+1)^4}\\
=&2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \left(H_{k+1}-\frac 1{k+1}\right)}{(k+1)^4} \\
=&2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}H_k}{k^4} -2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^5}\tag{$k+1\mapsto k$}\\
=&2\left(\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5) - \frac{\pi^2\zeta(3)}{12}\right)-2\cdot \frac{15}{16}\zeta(5)\\
=&\frac{29}{16}\zeta(5) - \frac{\pi^2}{6}\zeta(3)
\end{align*} where the known value of alternating Euler sum [$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \tfrac{(-1)^{k-1}H_k}{k^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883098/alternating-euler-sums/1883731#1883731) is used.

---

For $V_2$, we consider the algebraic identity
$$
6a^2b^2 = (a-b)^4 - a^4 +4a^3b +4ab^3 -b^4
$$ with $a=\ln y$ and $b = \ln(1+y)$ to get
\begin{align*}
V_2 =&\frac 1 6{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(\frac y{1+y}\right)}{1+y} dy}-\frac 1 6\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{1+y} dy +\underbrace{\frac 2 3\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 y\ln(1+y)}{1+y} dy}_{=2V_1}\\
&+\frac 2 3\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y\ln^3(1+y)}{1+y} dy}_{=- V_3\text{ by IBP}} -\frac 1 6\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}{1+y} dy\\
=&\frac 1 6 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x} dx -\frac 1 6\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{1+y} dy +2V_1-\frac 2 3 V_3 -\frac{\ln^5 2}{30}.\tag{$\tfrac y{1+y}= x$}
\end{align*}
For the first integral, we have 
\begin{align*}
W:=&\frac 1 6{\int_0^{\frac 1 2 }\frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x} dx}\tag{$2x\mapsto x$} \\
=& \frac 1 6\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(\tfrac x 2)}{2-x}dx\\
=&\frac 1 6\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\Big[\ln^4 x -4\ln 2 \ln^3 x + 6\ln^2 2\ln^2 x - 4\ln^3 2 \ln x + \ln^4 2\Big]dx\\
=&\frac 1 6\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\left[\frac{24}{k^5} + \frac{24\ln 2}{k^4} +\frac {12\ln^2 2}{k^3} +\frac{4\ln^3 2}{k^2} +\frac{\ln^4 2}{k}\right]\\
=&4\text{Li}_5(1/2) +4\ln 2\text{Li}_4(1/2) + 2\ln^2 2\text{Li}_3(1/2) + \frac{2\ln^3 2}{3}\text{Li}_2(1/2) + \frac{\ln^5 2}6\\
=&4\text{Li}_5(1/2) +4\ln 2\text{Li}_4(1/2) + \frac{7\ln^2 2}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{9}+ \frac{\ln^5 2}6.
\end{align*}

For the second integral, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac 1 6\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{1+y} dy
=& \frac 1 6\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \int_0^1 y^{k-1}\ln^4 y \ dy \\
=& \frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1} \frac{24}{k^5}\\
=&\frac{15}{4}\zeta(5).
\end{align*}

This gives
$$
V_2 = W +2V_1-\frac 2 3 V_3-\frac{15}{4}\zeta(5)-\frac{\ln^5 2}{30}.
$$

---

For $V_3$ we have
\begin{align*}
V_3=&\frac 14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+y)}{y}dy  \tag{$y\mapsto y+1$}\\
=& \frac 1 {4}{ \int_1^2 \frac{\ln^4 y }{y-1} dy} \tag{$\tfrac 1 y\mapsto y$}\\
=&\frac 1 {4} \int_{\frac 1 2}^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{y(1-y)} dy\\
=&\frac 1 {4} \int_{\frac 1 2}^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{y} dy+\frac 1 {4} \int_{\frac 1 2}^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{1-y} dy\\
=&\frac{\ln^5 2}{20} + \frac 1 {4} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{1-y} dy -\frac 1 {4} \underbrace{\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\frac{\ln^4 y}{1-y}dy}_{=6 W}\\
=&\frac{\ln^5 2}{20} +\frac 1 {4} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^1 y^{k-1}\ln^4 y\ dy- \frac 3 2 W\\
=&\frac{\ln^5 2}{20} +6\zeta(5)- \frac 3 2 W.
\end{align*}

---

Combining $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$, we get
\begin{align*}
J  = & V_2 -V_1+V_3 -\frac{\ln^5 2}{10}\\
=& \left[W+2V_1 -\frac 2 3 V_3-\frac{15}{4}\zeta(5)-\frac{\ln^5 2}{30}\right]-V_1+V_3 -\frac{\ln^5 2}{10}\\
=& W+V_1+\frac 1 3 V_3-\frac{15}{4}\zeta(5)-\frac{2\ln^5 2}{15}\\
=&\frac 1 2 W+V_1 -\frac 7 4\zeta(5) -\frac{7\ln^5 2}{60}\\
=&2\text{Li}_5(1/2) +2\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2) +\frac 1 {16}\zeta(5) -\frac{\pi^2}6 \zeta(3) +\frac {7\ln^2 2}{8} \zeta(3) -\frac{\ln^2 2\pi^3}{18}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{30}.
\end{align*}
This gives
\begin{align*}
I_1'' =&\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{288} -\frac{\ln^5 2}{8}+\frac 1 2\int_0^{\frac 1 2}\frac{\text{Li}_2^2(x)}{x} dx-J\\
=&\boxed{\small -3\text{Li}_5(1/2) -3\ln 2\text{Li}_4(1/2) +\frac{23}{64}\zeta(5) +\frac {23\pi^2}{96}\zeta(3) -\frac {21\ln^2 2}{16}\zeta(3) +\frac{7\pi^2\ln^3 2}{72} - \frac{3\ln^5 2}{20}.}
\end{align*}

---

For $I_1'''$, we exploit the symmetric nature of the integrand to write
\begin{align*}
I_1''' :=& \frac 1 2\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1-x)}{x(1-x)} dx\\
=& \frac 1 4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1-x)}{x(1-x)} dx \\
=& \frac 1 4\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1-x)}{x} dx}_{1-x\mapsto x}+\frac 1 4{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1-x)}{1-x} dx}\\
=&\frac 1 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \ln^2 (1-x)}{1-x} dx\\
=&\frac 1 2 \left[\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2 \partial y^2 } \text{B}(x,y)\right]_{x=1,y=0^+}
\end{align*} where $\text{B}(x,y)=\tfrac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ is Euler's Beta function. Now we can use the fact that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial x\partial y^2 }\text{B}(x,y)
=&-\frac 1 3\psi'''(x)+\psi''(x)\Big[\psi(x) +\gamma\Big]  + \psi'(x)\Big[\psi'(x)-\zeta(2) - \big[\psi(x) + \gamma\big]^2\Big]
\end{align*} to obtain
\begin{align*}
I_1'''=& \frac 1 2\frac d{dx}\left[\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial x\partial y^2 }\text{B}(x,0^+)\right]_{x=1} \\
=& -\frac 1 6 \psi''''(1) +\psi'(1)\psi''(1) \\
=&\boxed{4\zeta(5) -\frac{\pi^2}3 \zeta(3)}
\end{align*} where the values of $\psi(1) +\gamma = 0$, $\psi'(1) =\zeta(2)$, $\psi''(1) =-2\zeta(3)$ and $\psi''''(1) = -24\zeta(5)$ are used.

---

Finally, from $I_1 = I_1'+I_1''+I_1'''$ we get

> \begin{align*}
>  I_1 =&  -2\text{Li}_5(1/2) - 2\ln 2\text{Li}_4(1/2) + \frac {279}{64}\zeta(5) -\frac {3\pi^2}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac {7\ln^2 2}{8} \zeta(3)+\frac {\pi^2\ln^3 2}{18}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{15}.
> \end{align*}

---

For $I_2$, we observe that 
\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
I_2 =& \ln 2 \int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{\big[\text{Li}_2(x) + \ln^2(1-x)\big]\ln x}{x(1-x)} dx \\
=& \ln 2 {\int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \ln x}{1-x} dx}+\ln 2\int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln x}{1-x} dx+ \ln 2 \int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{\big[\text{Li}_2(x) + \ln^2(1-x)\big]\ln x}{x} dx\\
\underset{\text{IBP}}{=}&-\ln^3 2\ \text{Li}_2(1/2)+\ln 2 \int_0^{\frac 12} \ln(1-x)\frac{-\cancel{\ln(1-x)\ln x}+\text{Li}_2(x)}{x} dx \\
&+\ln2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln x}{1-x} dx + \ln 2{ \int_0^{\frac 12} \frac{\big[\text{Li}_2(x)+\cancel{ \ln^2(1-x)}\big] \ln x}{x} dx}\\
\underset{\text{IBP}}{=}&\small-\ln^3 2 \text{Li}_2(1/2)-\tfrac{\ln 2}{2} \left[\text{Li}^2_2(x)\right]^{1/2}_0-\frac{\ln^5 2}3+{\frac{\ln 2}3{\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x} dx}} -\ln^2 2\ \text{Li}_3(1/2)-\ln 2\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\text{Li}_3(x)}{x} dx\normalsize\\
=&-\ln^3 2\ \text{Li}_2(1/2) -\tfrac{\ln 2}{2} \text{Li}^2_2(1/2)-\frac{\ln^5 2}3+ \small\underbrace{\frac{\ln 2}3{\int_{\frac 1 2}^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x} dx}}_{1-x\mapsto x, \ =:I_2'}\normalsize-\ln^2 2\ \text{Li}_3(1/2)-\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)\\
=&-\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2) -\frac{7\ln^2 2}8 \zeta(3) -\frac{\pi^4 \ln 2}{288}+\frac {\pi^2\ln^3 2}{24}  -\frac{\ln^5 2}{8} +  I_2'.
\end{align*}

---

For $I_2'$, by integrating by parts, we have
\begin{align*}
I_2' 
=& \frac{\ln 2}3\int_{\frac 1 2}^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x} dx\\
=&\frac{\ln 2}3\int_{0}^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x} dx -\frac{\ln 2}3{\int_{0}^{\frac 12} \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x} dx}\tag{$x=\tfrac y 2$}\\
=&\frac{\ln 2}3\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\int_0^1 x^{k-1}\ln^3 x\ dx}-\underbrace{\frac{\ln 2}3\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^3 (\tfrac y 2)}{2-y} dy}_{=:A}\\
=&-\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{45}-A.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
A=&\frac{\ln 2}3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^k}\int_{0}^{1} y^{k-1}\ln^3 (\tfrac y 2) dy\\
=&\frac{\ln 2}3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^k}\int_{0}^{1} y^{k-1}\left[\ln^3 y - 3\ln 2\ln^2 y +3\ln^2 2\ln y -\ln^3 2\right]dy\\
=&-\frac{\ln 2}3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^k}\left[\frac 6 {k^4}+\frac{6\ln 2}{k^3} +\frac{3\ln^2 2}{k^2} +\frac{\ln^3 2}{k}\right]\\
=& -2\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2) - 2\ln^2 2\ \text{Li}_3(1/2)-\ln^3 2\ \text{Li}_2(1/2)-\frac{\ln^5 2}3\\
=&-2\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)-\frac{7\ln^2 2}{4}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{12}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{6}.
\end{align*}

---

This gives
$$
I_2'= 2\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)+\frac{7\ln^2 2}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4\ln 2}{45}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{12}-\frac{\ln^5 2}{6}
$$ and

> \begin{align*}
> I_2=\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2)+\frac{7\ln^2 2}{8}\zeta(3)-\frac{37\pi^4\ln 2}{1440}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^3 2}{24}+\frac{\ln^5 2}{24}.
> \end{align*}

---

For $I_3$, we have 
\begin{align*}
I_3=&\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)+\ln^2(1-x)}{x(1-x)}dx\\
=&\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}dx+\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\int_0^{\frac 1 2} {\left[\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}+\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}\right]}dx+\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\int_0^{\frac 1 2} \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}dx\\
=&\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\text{Li}_3(1/2) +\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}\big[-\ln(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x)\big]^{1/2}_0+\frac{\ln^5 2}6.
\end{align*} Using the well-known values of $\text{Li}_3(1/2)$ and $\text{Li}_2(1/2)$, this simplifies to

> $$
> I_3 =\frac {7\ln^2 2}{16}\zeta(3).
> $$

---

From $S = I_1+I_2 + I_3$, we finally get

> \begin{align*}
>  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2}{k^32^k} =& -2\text{Li}_5(1/2) -\ln 2\ \text{Li}_4(1/2) + \frac{279}{64}\zeta(5) - \frac{3\pi^2}{32}\zeta(3) + \frac{7\ln^2 2}{16}\zeta(3) - \frac{37\pi^4 \ln 2}{1440}\\
> & + \frac{\pi^2 \ln^3 2}{72} - \frac{\ln^5 2}{40}.
> \end{align*}

We can observe that the values of $I_2$ and $I_3$ can be used to evaluate  sums of lower order in a similar way:

> \begin{eqnarray*}
> &\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2}{k^2 2^k} = -\frac 1{\ln 2} I_2 - \frac{2}{\ln 2} I_3=-\text{Li}_4(1/2) -\frac{7\ln 2}4\zeta(3) +\frac{37 \pi^4}{1440} +\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{24} -\frac{\ln^4 2}{24},\\
> &\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2}{k 2^k} = \frac{2}{\ln^2 2} I_2 = \frac{7}{8}\zeta(3).
> \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: nice work (+1). my approach is somewhat shorter.

Comment: @AliShather Thank you :) It took too long to type all these equations...

Comment: its good to see different approaches though and that is the point of posting most of my problems.

Comment: the nice thing about your solution is that you didnt use results of other integrals/ sums unlike me where i used couple results.

Comment: @AliShather I wanted to see if this Euler sum involving a factor $2^{-k}$ can be transformed into the alternating one $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}H_k}{k^4}$ ($+$ some manageable integrals.)

Comment: these two sums can be found related by M.N.C.E here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944065/find-the-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2nn4/3195117#3195117

Comment: @AliShather Thank you for the reference.

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: wowza! (+1) $\qquad$

Comment: I just noticed that the integral $J$ gave you a hard time, here is a nice manipulation:

$$J=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx\overset{IBP}{=}\frac23{\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}}dx=\frac23\color{blue}{\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x}dx}$$

In this solution https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3329621

we proved 

$$\color{blue}{\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x}\ dx}=\frac3{16}\zeta(5)+\frac3{20}\ln^52-\frac14\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}\ dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x}\ dx$$

So by subbing the trvial integrals, we get $J$ easily :)

Answer (score 7):

We proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\tag{1}$$

multiply both sides by $\frac{\ln^2x}{x}$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$
we have

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\left(\frac{\ln^22}{n2^n}+\frac{2\ln2}{n^22^n}+\frac{2}{n^32^n}\right)\\
&=\ln^22\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n2^n}+2\ln2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^22^n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}\\
&=\ln^22S_1+2\ln2S_2+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}-2S_3
\end{align}

Rearranging the terms we have

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}=\frac12I-\frac12\ln^22S_1-\ln2S_2+S_3\tag{2}$$

---

**Evaluation of $I$:**

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx\overset{1-x\mapsto x}{=}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx\\
2I&=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x}\ dx+\underbrace{\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{1-x}\ dx}_{1-x\mapsto x}\\
I&=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x}\ dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n+1}\int_0^1x^n\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-4\zeta(5)=\boxed{8\zeta(5)-4\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}
\end{align}

where we used $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$

---

**Evaluation of $S_1$:**

Divide both sides of (1) by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$ and use the fact that $\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}=\frac1{n2^n}$

\begin{align}
S_1&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n2^n}=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\ dx\\
&=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\frac13\ln^32+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\frac13\ln^32+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac2{n^3}-\frac{\ln^22}{n2^n}-\frac{2\ln2}{n^22^n}-\frac{2}{n^32^n}\right)\\
&=\frac13\ln^32+2\zeta(3)-\ln^32-2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)=\boxed{\frac14\zeta(3)}
\end{align}

where we used $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)=\frac12\zeta(2)-\frac12\ln^22$ and $\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)=\frac78\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln2\zeta(2)+\frac16\ln^32$

---

**Evaluation of $S_2$:**

integrate both sides of (1) from $x=0$ to $x$ to have

$$-\frac13\ln^3(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\tag{3}$$

Now divide both sides of (3) by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$ and use the fact that $\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}=\frac1{n2^n}$

$$-\frac13\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^22^n}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$

Rearranging the terms

$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^22^n}=\boxed{2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^32^n}-\frac13\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)}$$

---

**Evaluation of $S_3$:**

By Cauchy product we have

$$\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(\frac{4H_n}{n^3}+\frac{2H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}-\frac{6}{n^4}\right)$$

divide both sides by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$ and use the fact that $\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}=\frac1{n2^n}$ we have

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n}\left(\frac{4H_n}{n^3}+\frac{2H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}-\frac{6}{n^4}\right)$$

rearrange to get

$$S_3=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}=\boxed{3\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^42^n}+\frac12\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx}$$

---

Substituting the results of $I$, $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ in (2) we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}=3\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+4\zeta(5)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac18\ln^22\zeta(3)-2\left(\color{blue}{\ln2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^32^n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^42^n}}\right)+\frac13\ln2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\frac12\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx$$

I managed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3195117) to prove

$$\color{blue}{\ln2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{2^n n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{2^nn^4}
}=-\frac12\ln^22\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{2^n n^2}-\frac16\ln^32\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{2^n n}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac{47}{32}\zeta(5)+\frac{1}{15}\ln^52+\frac{1}{3}\ln^32\operatorname{Li_2}\left( \frac12\right)+\ln^22\operatorname{Li_3}\left( \frac12\right)+2\ln2\operatorname{Li_4}\left( \frac12\right) +2\operatorname{Li_5}\left( \frac12\right)$$

plugging the trivial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{ n^22^n}=\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)\zeta(2)$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n2^n}=\frac12\zeta(2)$ we get

$$\color{blue}{\ln2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{2^n n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{2^nn^4}
}=2\operatorname{Li}_5\left( \frac12\right)+2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left( \frac12\right)+\frac1{32}\zeta(5)-\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac38\ln^22\zeta(3)\\-\frac16\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac1{15}\ln^52$$

Also @Song nicely proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325928)

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx=\frac12\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac78\ln^22\zeta(3)-\frac58\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac{27}{32}\zeta(5)+\frac78\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\-\frac{7}{60}\ln^52-2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)$$

for the integral:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx&=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3x\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\ln^32}{n2^n}+\frac{3\ln^22}{n^22^n}+\frac{6\ln2}{n^32^n}+\frac{6}{n^42^n}-\frac{6}{n^4}\right)\\
&=\ln^42+3\ln^32\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)+6\ln2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)+6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-6\zeta(4)\\
&=6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-6\zeta(4)+\frac{21}4\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac32\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac12\ln^42
\end{align}

---

Combining these results we get

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}=-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{279}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac{37}{16}\ln2\zeta(4)-\frac{9}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\+\frac{7}{16}\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac1{12}\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{40}\ln^52$$

---

**BONUS:**

In our solution we got

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}=3\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^42^n}+\frac12\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\ dx$$

Substitute

\begin{align}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^42^n}&=2\operatorname{Li_5}\left( \frac12\right)+\ln2\operatorname{Li_4}\left( \frac12\right)-\frac16\ln^32\zeta(2)
+\frac12\ln^22\zeta(3)\\
&\quad-\frac18\ln2\zeta(4)- 
\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac1{32}\zeta(5)+\frac1{40}\ln^52
\end{align}

along with @Song's result we get

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}=-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-3\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{23}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac1{16}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac{23}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\-\frac{23}{16}\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac7{12}\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{13}{120}\ln^52$$

Answer (score 1):

**Different Solution with a big bonus:**

First lets define the following:

$$M=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}$$

$$N=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}$$

I am going to establish two relations of $M$ and $N$ and solve them as a system of equations.

---

**The first relation:**

In the question body, we reached

$$M+N=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x/2)}{x}dx$$

and by using $\quad\displaystyle\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{1-xy}dy\quad$ we can write

$$M+N=-\frac12\int_0^1\ln y\left[\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-(y/2)x}dx\right]dy$$

$$=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{y}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-2}\right)dy\overset{IBP}{=}-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)}{y}\ln^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)dy$$

$$\small{=-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)}{y}\left[\ln^22+2\ln2\ln y+\ln^2y-2\ln2\ln(1+y)-2\ln y\ln(1+y)+\ln^2(1+y)\right]dy}$$

$$=-\ln^22\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)}{y}dy}_{I_1}-2\ln2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)\ln y}{y}dy}_{I_2}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)\ln^2y}{y}dy}_{I_3}\\+2\ln2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)\ln(1+y)}{y}dy}_{I_4}+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)\ln y\ln(1+y)}{y}dy}_{I_5}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)\ln^2(1+y)}{y}dy}_{I_6}$$

$$I_1=\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)=-\frac34\zeta(3)$$

$$I_2\overset{IBP}{=}-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-y)}{y}dy=-\operatorname{Li}_4(-1)=\frac78\zeta(4)$$

$$I_3\overset{IBP}{=}-2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-y)\ln y}{y}dy\overset{IBP}{=}2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(-y)}{y}dy=2\operatorname{Li}_5(-1)=-\frac{15}8\zeta(5)$$

$$I_4=-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-1)=-\frac5{16}\zeta(4)$$

$$I_5\overset{IBP}{=}\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(-y)}{y}dy=\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{17}{32}\zeta(5)$$

where the last result follows from [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236084), check Eq$(3)$

$I_6$ is elegantly evaluated by Cornel [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336378340_The_calculation_of_a_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_the_product_of_harmonic_numbers_H_n_H_2_2n) in page $5$ and by me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3462815),

$$\small{I_6=4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+4\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{125}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{7}{4}\ln^22\zeta(3)-\frac2{3}\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac{2}{15}\ln^52}$$

Combine these results to obtain

> $$M+N=-4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-4\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{131}{32}\zeta(5)$$
>   $$-\frac{19}{8}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac{7}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac2{3}\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{2}{15}\ln^52\tag1$$

---

**The second relation:**

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\tag2$$

multiply both sides by $\frac{\ln^2x}{x}$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$
we have

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\left(\frac{\ln^22}{n2^n}+\frac{2\ln2}{n^22^n}+\frac{2}{n^32^n}\right)\\
&=\ln^22\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n2^n}+2\ln2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^22^n}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^32^n}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^32^n}\\
&=\ln^22S_1+2\ln2S_2+2M-2N
\end{align}

Or

$$M-N=\frac12I-\frac12\ln^22S_1-\ln2S_2$$

**Evaluation of $I:$**

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx\overset{1-x\mapsto x}{=}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx\\
2I&=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x}\ dx+\underbrace{\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{1-x}\ dx}_{1-x\mapsto x}\\
I&=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln^2x}{x}\ dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n+1}\int_0^1x^n\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-4\zeta(5)=8\zeta(5)-4\zeta(2)\zeta(3)
\end{align}

**Evaluation of $S_1$:**

Divide both sides of (2) by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$ and use the fact that $\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}=\frac1{n2^n}$

\begin{align}
S_1&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n2^n}=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\ dx\\
&=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{\ln^2x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\frac13\ln^32+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\frac13\ln^32+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac2{n^3}-\frac{\ln^22}{n2^n}-\frac{2\ln2}{n^22^n}-\frac{2}{n^32^n}\right)\\
&=\frac13\ln^32+2\zeta(3)-\ln^32-2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)=\frac14\zeta(3)
\end{align}

where we used $\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)=\frac12\zeta(2)-\frac12\ln^22$ and $\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)=\frac78\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln2\zeta(2)+\frac16\ln^32$

**Evaluation of $S_2$:**

integrate both sides of (2) from $x=0$ to $x$ to have

$$-\frac13\ln^3(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\tag{3}$$

Now divide both sides of (3) by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1/2$ and use the fact that $\int_0^{1/2}x^{n-1}=\frac1{n2^n}$

$$-\frac13\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^22^n}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$

Rearranging the terms

$$S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^22^n}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^32^n}-\frac13\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)$$

[Substitute](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3195207)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{2^nn^3}=\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac18\zeta(4)-\frac18\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac1{24}\ln^42$$

and

\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx&=\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3x\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\ln^32}{n2^n}+\frac{3\ln^22}{n^22^n}+\frac{6\ln2}{n^32^n}+\frac{6}{n^42^n}-\frac{6}{n^4}\right)\\
&=\ln^42+3\ln^32\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac12\right)+6\ln2\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)+6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-6\zeta(4)\\
&=6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-6\zeta(4)+\frac{21}4\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac32\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac12\ln^42
\end{align}

we get

$$S_2=-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac94\zeta(4)-2\ln2\zeta(3)+\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)-\frac1{12}\ln^42$$

collect the results of $I$, $S_1$ and $S_2$ we get

> $$M-N=2\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+4\zeta(5)$$
>   $$-\frac{9}{4}\ln2\zeta(4)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{15}8\ln^22\zeta(3)-\frac1{2}\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^52\tag4$$

---

Now we are ready to calculate the two sums:

$$M=\frac{(1)+(4)}{2}=-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{279}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac{37}{16}\ln2\zeta(4)-\frac{9}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\+\frac{7}{16}\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac1{12}\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{40}\ln^52$$

$$N=\frac{(1)-(4)}{2}=-2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-3\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{23}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac1{16}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac{23}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\-\frac{23}{16}\ln^22\zeta(3)+\frac7{12}\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{13}{120}\ln^52$$