# Contest math problem: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\{H_n\}}{n^2}$

Tags: summation, contest-math, harmonic-numbers

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\{H_n\}}{n^2}$$

I have managed to prove that it converges, but am having trouble with a closed form. This came from a school contest from last year, but can't really figure it out.

I came up with a numeric solution, but am having lots of trouble with the closed form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $\{H_n\}$ the fractional part of $H_n$?

Comment: Sorry about that other problem, everybody. I had issues with the composition of the problem itself

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, and $H_n$ denotes the $n$ th harmonic number

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}$ already converges, to $2\zeta(3)$.

Comment: @Slade I am aware

Comment: @Slade I actually tried using that and the definition of "{n}" as in n-floor(n) but note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges

Comment: Is $\zeta(3)$ considered a "closed form"?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I believe so, yes.

Comment: @Apple Cuz $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ but $\zeta(3)$ is just $\sum\frac1{n^3}$ which is well known to be unknown.  So I always took it as $\zeta(3)$ has no known closed form, while $\zeta(2)$ does.  But it's just terminology, I take it you're happy with a solution in terms of $\zeta$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Lol, yes I am

Comment: $\zeta(3)$ is known as "Apéry's constant" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apéry%27s_theorem

Comment: The numerical value for the sum (to an accuracy of $10^{-5}$) is $0.32830$

Comment: What contest is this from? I'd love to see more.

Comment: @Patrick School contest, so local

Comment: @JohnVine Really? What country? This looks pretty hard for a local contest. I almost wonder if a different problem was intended instead (like the one answered below).

Comment: @Patrick Yes this was local. But it was too hard so the person running the contest disbanded the problem. I was still curious so I asked it here.

Answer (score 5):

Note: this is the answer to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}$ instead of the one $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\{H_n\}}{n^2}$ in the question.

---

First the $n$-the harmonic number can be written as
$$
H_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}=\int_{0}^1 \left(1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}\right)dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}\right)dx.$$
By the Taylor expansion of $\log(1-t)$,
$$ \log(1-t) =-\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{t^n}{n}+\cdots\right),$$
we can write
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{n^2} = -\int_0^x \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}dt
$$
which is exactly the [dilogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) $\mbox{Li}_2(x)$.

Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}
=-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x}\int_x^1 \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}dt dx
=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-x}dxdt
=\int_0^1 \frac{(\log(1-t))^2}{t}dt
$$
The final step is to convert the above integral into some integral representation of the [Riemann Zeta function](http://%5Csum_%7Bn=1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7BH_n%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%20=). For example, using the 
change of variable $s=-\log(1-t)$, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}=\int\frac{s^2}{e^s-1}ds=\Gamma(3)\zeta(3)=2\zeta(3).
$$

Comment: Hi. You seem to be answering a different question. This one takes the fractional part of each $H_n$ before summing.

Comment: @Patrick you are right. I didn't read all the comments carefully following the question.

Comment: $\{H_n\}=H_n-[H_n].$

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to the actual question, but some thoughts, some useful references and a derivation of a good approximation to the sum.

---

We can rewrite the sum as (see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909228/a-sum-containing-harmonic-numbers-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn3-2n?rq=1) or the answer above for the $2\zeta(3)$ evaluation)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\{ H_n \}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor H_n \rfloor}{n^2} = 2\zeta(3) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor H_n \rfloor}{n^2}$$
and we can further rewrite
$$
\begin{array}{cll}\tag{1}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor H_n \rfloor}{n^2} &=& 1\left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{3^2}\right) \\&+& 2\left(\frac{1}{4^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{10^2}\right) \\&+& 3\left(\frac{1}{11^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{30^2}\right) \\&+& 4\left(\frac{1}{31^2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{82^2}\right) \\&+& \ldots\\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\sum_{j=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{j^2}
\end{array}
$$
where $n_k$ are defined as the smallest integer where $\lfloor H_n\rfloor = k$. Since $H_n = \log(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$ we expect $n_k = \lfloor e^{k-\gamma} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor$. This formula holds for $k\leq 100$ and heuristics suggest that it could hold for all $k$, see comments in OEIS [A002387](https://oeis.org/A002387) and *R. P. Boas, Jr. and J. W. Wrench, Jr., [Partial Sums of the Harmonic Series](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316476), The American Mathematical Monthly*.

Evaluating the sum requires knowledge of $n_k$ and since this is not known in the litterature (as far as I have chekced) it seems unlikely that the problem has a (known) closed form solution. Even if the simple formula for $n_k$ holds it still seems pretty hopeless to evaluate the sums, however it gives us a good starting point for an approximation. We can approximate

$$\sum_{j=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{j^2} \approx \int_{n_k}^{n_{k+1}}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x^2} = \frac{(n_{k+1}-n_k)}{n_kn_{k+1}}$$

Now if we take $n_k = e^{k-\gamma}$ in the expression above then the integral is $(e-1)e^{\gamma-1-k}$ and the resulting sum can be evaluated analytically. A good approximation can be found by explicitly summing the first $K-1$ brackets in $(1)$ and using the approximation above to estimate the rest of the terms. This leads to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\{H_n\}}{n^2} \approx 2\zeta(3)-\sum_{k=1}^{K-1} k\sum_{j=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{j^2} -\frac{K(e-1)+1}{(e-1)e^{K-\gamma}}$$

Taking $K=5$ gives us
$$2\zeta(3)-2.00822-\frac{5 (e-1) + 1}{(e-1)e^{5-\gamma}} \approx 0.32890$$

which is within $0.2\%$ of the exact result (found by summing numerically up to $n=10^7$).