# Find $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In solving $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\dfrac{\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)}{\sin x\cos x}\ dx,$ I have found that this is equal to $\dfrac{1}{16}\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx.$ WolframAlpha says that the desired value is $\dfrac{\zeta(3)}{8},$ so I suspect a conversion to a series is necessary.

How do I prove $\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{n^3}$?

Note that the above integral can also be given as $\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{\ln^2x}{1-x}\ dx$, which I know is equal to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\ln^2x.$

Also for reference, here is a picture of my original work to get to this point.

[image]

Comment: What's up with everyone usign \displaystyle lately? We don't need that anywhere, especially in the title

Comment: @You'reInMyEye That's just how I write integrals. Chalk it up to me not having a lot of experience on Math.SE and not knowing all of the minutiae that you all prefer. My apologies.

Comment: Eridan, that was nothing personal, more a comment for general public. I edited at least three displaystyle titles today. I'm not sure myself why it's not allowed, but I think it may cause some problems with browsing question and search

Comment: @You'reInMyEye MSE strongly recommends ( in some documentation ) to avoid $\texttt{displaystyle}$ in the title.

Comment: Is $\ln^2 x$ a standard notation?

Comment: @StubbornAtom To my knowledge, yes. It is an identical usage as, for example, $\sin^2x$.

Comment: @Eridan Technically, it works for the trigonometric functions. But for any function $f$, $f^2(x)$ could mean $(f(x))^2, f''(x)$ or $f(f(x))$. Honestly I haven't seen that notation used in a proper textbook instead of $(\ln x)^2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom While I don't have my most recent calculus textbook at hand, I believe it is used there. For one thing, however, $f^2(x)$ is definitely not the notation for $f''(x)$; that would be $f^{(2)}(x)$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}\left(1-x\right)}{x}dx\stackrel{x\rightarrow1-x}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{2}\left(x\right)}{1-x}dx$$ $$\stackrel{DCT}{=}
 \sum_{k\geq0}\int_{0}^{1}\log^{2}\left(x\right)x^{k}dx\stackrel{IBP}{=}
 2\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)^{3}}=\color{red}{2\zeta\left(3\right)}.$$

Comment: Can you please tell me what $DCT$ means.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I believe it's the dominated convergence theorem which allows him to switch the integral sign with the sum, since he used a geometric series representation of $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that exploits the [Polylogarithm Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).  To that end, we proceed.

Note that integrating by parts with $u=\log^2(1-x)$ and $v=\log(x)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-x)}{x}\,dx=2\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Integrating by parts the right-hand side of $(1)$ with $u=\log(1-x)$ and $v=\text{Li}_2(1-x)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
2\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=2\text{Li}_3(1)\\\\
&=2\zeta(3)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

1. This one is $\ul{slightly\ different}$ of the straightforward [@Dr. MV answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882731/85343):
   \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{{1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} &\,\,\,
   \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ \pars{1 - x}}{=}\,\,\,
   {1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
   \end{align}

   ---

   *Integrating by Parts* a few times ( the main purpose is to 'sit' a
   $\ds{\ln\pars{1 - x}}$-factor in the integrand numerator ): 
   \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{{1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} & =
   {1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 - x}
   \bracks{2\ln\pars{x}\,{1 \over x}}\,\dd x = 
   -\,{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}\Li{2}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   {1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}\Li{2}\pars{x}\,{1 \over x}\,\dd x =
   {1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}\Li{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x = {1 \over 8}\,\Li{3}\pars{1}
   \\[5mm] & = \color{#f00}{{1 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
   \end{align}
2. Another approach uses the *Beta Function*
   $\ds{\mrm{B}\pars{\mu,\nu} =
   \int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - 1}\,\pars{1 - x}^{\nu - 1}\,\,\dd x =
   {\Gamma\pars{\mu}\Gamma\pars{\nu} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu}}}$ with
   $\ds{\Re\pars{\mu} > 0\,,\ \Re\pars{\nu} > 0}$. $\ds{\Gamma\,}$: *Gamma
   Function*.
   \begin{align}
   &\color{#f00}{{1 \over 16}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} =
   {1 \over 16}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\,\partiald[2]{}{\mu}
   \int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{\mu} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   {1 \over 16}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0}\,\,\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\bracks{\mu
   \int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu - 1}\,\dd x} =
   {1 \over 16}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0 \atop \nu \to 0}\,\,{\partial^{3} \over \partial\mu^{2}\,\partial\nu}
   \bracks{\mu\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu}\pars{1 - x}^{\mu - 1}\,\dd x}
   \\[5mm] & =
   {1 \over 16}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0 \atop \nu \to 0}\,\,{\partial^{3} \over \partial\mu^{2}\,\partial\nu}\bracks{\mu\,{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}\Gamma\pars{\mu} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1}}} =
   {1 \over 16}\,\lim_{\mu \to 0 \atop \nu \to 0}\,\,{\partial^{3} \over \partial\mu^{2}\,\partial\nu}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1}}
   \\[5mm] & = \color{#f00}{{1 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
   \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that makes use of an [Euler sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html).

We will first find a Maclaurin series expansion for $\ln^2 (1 - x)$. As 
$$\ln (1 - x) = - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n},$$
we have
\begin{align*}
\ln^2 (1 - x) &= \left (- \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \right ) \cdot \left (- \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \right ).
\end{align*}
Shifting the summation index $n \mapsto n + 1$ gives
\begin{align*}
\ln^2 (1 - x) &= x^2 \left (- \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n + 1} \right ) \cdot \left (- \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n + 1} \right )\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^{n + 2}}{(k + 1)(n - k + 1)},
\end{align*}
where the last line has been obtained by applying the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series).

Shifting the summation indices as follows: $n \mapsto n - 2, k \mapsto k - 1$ gives
\begin{align*}
\ln^2 (1 - x) &= \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{x^n}{k(n - k)}\\
&= \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \left (\frac{1}{nk} + \frac{1}{n(n - k)} \right ) x^n\\
&= 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{k}\\
&= 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1} x^n}{n},
\end{align*}
where $H_n$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Now evaluating the integral. From the above Maclaurin series expansion for $\ln^2 (1 - x)$ the integral can be written as
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1 - x)}{x} \, dx &= 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1}}{n} \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \, dx = 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1}}{n^2}.
\end{align*}

From properties of the harmonic numbers we have
$$H_n = H_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n},$$
thus
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1 - x)}{x} \, dx &= 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} - 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} = 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} - 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}.
\end{align*}

Each sum can be readily found. They are:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} = \zeta (3) \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} = 2 \zeta (3).$$
A proof of the result for the second sum containing the harmonic number can, for example, be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591140/contest-math-problem-sum-n-1-infty-frac-h-n-n2/1591372#1591372). Thus
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (1 - x)}{x} \, dx = 4 \zeta (3) - 2 \zeta (3) = 2 \zeta (3),$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you did is good. Indeed, it suffices to show that $I_n:=\int_0^1 x^n \ln^2 x = \frac{2}{(n+1)^3}$ to conclude. The interversion $\int / \Sigma$ is possible as everything here is positive.

To compute $I_n$, I tried an integration by parts (using that a primitive of $\ln^2 x$ is $x(\ln^2 x-2\ln x)$) to obtain the relation $$I_n = \frac{-2}{n+1}\int_0^1 x^n\ln x.$$
Let us call this latter integral $J_n$. Once again with an integration by parts, you can show that $J_n = \frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}$, and thus conclude.