# Simple, yet evasive integral from zero to $\pi/2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> **Q:** Evaluate$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm dx}\newcommand{\du}{\mathrm du}\newcommand{\dv}{\mathrm dv}\newcommand{\dtheta}{\mathrm d\theta}\newcommand{\dw}{\mathrm dw}$$$I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\dx\,\frac {\left(\log\sin x\log\cos x\right)^2}{\sin x\cos x}$$

I'm out of ideas on what to do. I tried using the astute limit identity for integration, but that lead to nowhere, because it's simply the same integral i.e adding the two together, doesn't yield a simplification whatsoever$$I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\dx\,\frac {\log^2\sin x\log^2\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\du\,\frac {\log^2\cos u\log^2\sin u}{\cos u\sin u}$$I've looked into making a u-substitution, but have no idea where to begin. I plan to use a trigonometric identity, namely$$\sec x\csc x=\cot x+\tan x$$but I'm not sure what to do afterwards because we get$$I=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\dx\,\cot x\log^2\sin x\log^2\cos x+\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\dx\,\tan x\log^2\sin x\log^2\cos x$$I would appreciate it if you guys gave me an idea on where to begin!

Also, as a side note, I've used `\newcommand` on `\dx`,`\du`,`\dv`, and `\dw` to automatically change to $\dx$, $\du$, $\dv$, and $\dw$ respectively, if you guys don't mind! Just to make it easier for the differential operator!

Comment: It seems to be $\frac{1}{24}(12\zeta(5) - \pi^2\zeta(3)) \approx 0.02413778999736$

Comment: Hint: change variable to $t = \sin(x)^2$ and get rid of all trigonometric function.

Comment: What makes you say that it is simple ???

Comment: What is this... A strange integral, and no Jack? Should we worry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change variable to $t = \sin^2 x$ and notice
$$\begin{align}\frac{dx}{\sin x\cos x} &= \frac{\sin x\cos x dx}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x} = \frac12\frac{dt}{t(1-t)}\\
 \log\sin x \log\cos x &= \frac14\log\sin^2 x \log \cos^2 x = \frac14 \log t\log(1-t)
\end{align}
$$
The integral at hand can be rewritten as
$$\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\log\sin x\log\cos x)^2}{\sin x\cos x} dx = \frac{1}{32}\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 t \log^2(1-t)}{t(1-t)} dt$$
Since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{t(1-t)} = \frac1t + \frac{1}{1-t}$, by replacing $t$ by $1-t$ in part of the integral, we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} 
&= \frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 t\log^2(1-t)}{t} dt
= \frac{1}{48}\int_0^1 \log^2(1-t) d\log^3 t\\
&\stackrel{\text{I.by.P}}{=} \frac{1}{48}\left\{
\left[\log^2(1-t)\log^3 t\right]_0^1 + 2
\int_0^1 \log^3 t\frac{\log(1-t)}{1-t}dt\right\}\\
&= -\frac{1}{24}\int_0^1  \frac{\log^3 t}{1-t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n} dt
= -\frac{1}{24}\int_0^1 \log^3 t\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nt^n dt\\
&\stackrel{t = e^{-y}}{=} \frac{1}{24} \int_0^\infty y^3 \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n e^{-(n+1)y} dy
= \frac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}
\end{align}
$$
where $H_n$ are the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). By rearranging its terms, the last sum should be expressible in terms of zeta functions. I'm lazy, I just ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[HarmonicNumber[n]%2F%28n%2B1%29%5E4,%7Bn,1,Inf%7D]) to evaluate the sum. As expected, last sum equals to $2\zeta(5) - \frac{\pi^2}{6}\zeta(3)$${}^\color{blue}{[1]}$.

As a consequence, the integral at hand equals to:

$$\mathcal{I} 
= \frac{12\zeta(5) - \pi^2\zeta(3)}{24}
\approx 0.024137789997360933616411382857235691008...$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ It turns out we can compute this sum using an
  identity by Euler.
  $$2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^m} = (m+2)\zeta(m+1) - \sum_{n=1}^{m-2}\zeta(m-n)\zeta(n+1),\quad\text{ for } m = 2, 3, \ldots$$
  In particular, for $m = 4$, this identity becomes
  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(n)}{n^4}
  = 3\zeta(5) - \zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$
  and we can evaluate our sum as
  $$\begin{align}\mathcal{I} 
  &= \frac14\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{(n+1)^4}
  = \frac14\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{H_{n+1}}{(n+1)^4}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^5}\right)
  = \frac14\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} - \zeta(5)\right)\\
  &= \frac14(2\zeta(5) - \zeta(2)\zeta(3))
  = \frac{12\zeta(5) - \pi^2\zeta(3)}{24}
  \end{align}
  $$

Comment: How did you get to the step below?$$\mathcal{I} = \frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 t\log^2(1-t)}{t} dt
= \frac{1}{48}\int_0^1 \log^2(1-t) d\log^3 t$$

Comment: @Crescendo
$$\begin{align}&\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(t)\log^2(1-t)}{t(1-t)}dt
= \int_0^1\log^2(t)\log^2(1-t)\left(\frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{1-t}\right)dt\\
\stackrel{s=1-t}{=} &
\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(t)\log^2(1-t)}{t}dt +
\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1-s)\log^2(s)}{s}ds
= 2\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(t)\log^2(1-t)}{t}dt
\end{align}
$$
and
 $$d\log^3(t) = \frac{d(\log^3(t))}{dt} dt = 3\log^2(t)\frac{d\log(t)}{dt} dt = 3 \frac{\log^2(t)}{t}dt$$

Comment: So you're using differentiation under the integral? I'm having trouble understanding your notation $d\,\log^3t$ for some reason...

Comment: @Crescendo For your purpose,  you can either view $\int f(x)dg(x)$ as a short-hand for $\int f(x)g'(x)dx$ or as a [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). I personally view those things as integration involving differential forms. (which have richer algebraic properties and allow more flexiable manipulation of the expression)

Comment: One last question: How does$$\frac {1}{1-t}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac {t^n}n=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}H_n t^n$$I think you represented the $1/(1-t)$ fraction as its infinite geometric sequence, but I'm not seeing how that equals the right-hand side.

Comment: @Crescendo In general, if function $f(t)$ has a power series representation $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$ over some neighbor of $t = 0$, then $\frac{f(t)}{1-t}$ has power series representation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sum_{k=0}^n a_k) t^n$. Above identity is a special case of that.

Answer (score 1):

I will work with the integral found after a substitution of $t = \sin^2 x$ has been made so that
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln^2 (\sin x) \ln^2 (\cos x)}{\sin x \cos x} \, dx = \frac{1}{32} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t \ln^2 (1 - t)}{t (1 - t)} \, dt.$$

---

The first method that comes to mind is to evaluate the integral appearing to the right as the derivative of a beta function. Since
$$\text{B} (x,y) = \int_0^1 t^{x - 1} (1 - t)^{y - 1} \, dt,$$
we see that
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{y \to 0^+} \partial^2_x \partial^2_y \text{B}(x,y) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t \ln^2 (1 - t)}{t (1 - t)} \, dt.$$
Thus
$$I = \frac{1}{32} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{y \to 0^+} \partial^2_x \partial^2_y \text{B}(x,y).$$
While the above calculation is doable, it is far from trivial (at least "by hand") and will accordingly not be given here.

---

As a second method, I will make use of the following Maclaurin series expansion for the term $\ln^2 (1 - t)$ which is given by
$$\ln^2 (1 - t) = 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1}}{n} t^n, \qquad |t| < 1, \tag1$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). A proof of this result can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882695/find-int-01-frac-ln21-xx-dx/2589657#2589657).

As
$$\frac{1}{t(1 - t)} = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{1 - t},$$
we can write the integral $I$ as
$$I = \frac{1}{32} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t \ln^2 (1 - t)}{t} \, dt + \frac{1}{32} \frac{\ln^2 t \ln^2 (1 - t)}{1 - t} \, dt.$$
If in the second of these integrals we enforce a substitution of $t \mapsto 1 - t$ we have
$$I = \frac{1}{16} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t \ln^2 (1 - t)}{t} \, dt.$$

Replacing the term $\ln^2(1 - t)$ with its Maclaurin series expansion, after interchanging the summation with the integral sign we have
$$I = \frac{1}{8} \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1}}{n} \int_0^1 t^{n - 1} \ln^2 t \, dt.$$
The integral that results can be readily found using integration by parts twice. The result is
$$\int_0^1 t^{n - 1} \ln^2 t \, dt = \frac{2}{n^3}.$$
Thus
$$I = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1}}{n^4}.$$

Since
$$H_n = H_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n},$$
we have
$$I = \frac{1}{4} \left [\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} - \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} \right ] =  \frac{1}{4} \left [\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} \right ].$$

The value for the *Euler sum* is well-known (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555266/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-n2n3/564953#564953) for example). It is
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} = 3 \zeta (5) - \zeta (2) \zeta (3),$$
while the second sum is just the zeta function $\zeta (5)$. Thus
$$I = \frac{1}{4} \big{[}3 \zeta (5) - \zeta (2) \zeta (3) - \zeta (5) \big{]},$$
or
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\ln^2 (\sin x) \ln^2 (\cos x)}{\sin x \cos x} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \big{[} 2 \zeta (5) - \zeta (2) \zeta (3) \Big{]}.$$