# Is the following Harmonic Number Identity true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

> **Is the following identity true?**
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_nx^n}{n^3} = \frac12\zeta(3)\ln x-\frac18\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\right] + \operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x+\frac{\pi^4}{60}$$

In [this accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909228/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn32n), [@Tunk Fey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/123277/tunk-fey) proved the above. (See $(4)$). However, I have the following $3$ queries :

- **Why can we add the integrals after the substitution $x \mapsto 1-x$ in the following step? I doubt it since $\int f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x \neq \int f(1-x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ in general.**

> [image]

- **Why do we omit the constant of integration in the following step? We should add the constant since it will affect the summation.**

> $$\begin{align}
> \color{red}{\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}&=-\int\frac{\ln (1-x)\ln^2 x}{1-x}\ dx\\
> &=\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n x^n\ln^2x\ dx\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \int x^n\ln^2x\ dx\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}\left[\int x^n\ dx\right]\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}\left[\frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n \left[\frac{x^{n+1}\ln^2x}{n+1}-2\frac{x^{n+1}\ln x}{(n+1)^2}+2\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\right]\\
> &=\ln^2x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n x^{n+1}}{n+1}-2\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\\
> &=\frac12\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)-2\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\right]\\&+2\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n+1} x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^4}\right]\\
> &=\frac12\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)-2\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n^3}\right]\\&+2\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n^4}\right]\\
> &=\frac12\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)-2\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\right]\\&+2\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^3}-\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\right].
> \end{align}$$

- **Is the identity even true, since putting $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ gives a [numerically different result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%20zeta(3)ln(1%2F2)-1%2F8%20ln%5E4(1%2F2)%2B%201%2F2%20ln(1%2F2)(zeta(3)-(pi%5E2%2F12)ln(2)-trilog(1%2F2))%2Bpolylog%5B4,%201%2F2%5D-(pi%5E2%2F12)dilog(1%2F2)-1%2F2%20trilog(1%2F2)ln(1%2F2)%2B(pi%5E4%2F60)) than [the correct result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E4%2F(720)+%2B+ln%5E4(2)%2F(24)+-+ln(2)%2F(8)+zeta(3)+%2B+Polylog(4,1%2F2)), as pointed out by the user [@Super Abound](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/140590/superabound) in the comments of that answer.**

Please help.

Comment: Yes Integration constant should've been taken care of. That is indeed creating a problem. Those should've been definite integrals, say, from 0 to x. The ignorance of the constant has had an impact on the answer.

Comment: Nobody answers it here.. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** OPs doubts seem reasonable to me, since the identity stated in OPs question is *not correct*. In the following we are going through @TunkFey's answer and try to put the focus to weak points in his argumentation. But, nevertheless I'd like to emphasize that it was a pleasure to go through his answer which was also *instructive and inspiring* to me.

> **Preliminaries**

> The challenge in Tunk Feys answer was to find a closed expression (at least in terms of *[Polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)*)  of
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_nx^n}{n^3} 
> \end{align*}
> and evaluate it at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

[Raymond Manzoni](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/605602/123277) has nicely  demonstrated that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_nx^n}{n^2}&=\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\\
&\qquad+\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\tag{1}
 \end{align*}
Tunk Fey took this series as starting point and decided to use the same techniques as Raymond.

> (Tunk Fey:) Dividing (1) by $x$ and integrating gives
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_nx^n}{n^3}
> &=\zeta(3)\ln x+\frac12\color{red}{\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}+\color{blue}{\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}x\ dx}\\&+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\color{green}{\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)}x\ dx}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

The next step is to simplify
\begin{align*}
\color{green}{\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)}x\ dx}
\end{align*}

He continues with (question marks emphasis mine)

> (Tunk Fey:) Using IBP to evaluate the green integral by setting $u=\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)$ and $dv=\frac1x\ dx$, we obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{green}{\int\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)}x\ dx}&=\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x+\int\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx\qquad x\mapsto1-x\\
> &\stackrel{???}{=}\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x-\color{blue}{\int\frac{\ln (1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx}.\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

---

> **OP: Why can we add the integrals after the substitution $x \mapsto 1-x$ in the following step? I doubt it since $\int f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x \neq \int f(1-x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ in general.**

The substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$ is *not valid* in Tunk Fey's answer. We can use it e.g. in case of definite integrals by also respecting the limits of the integral. But as OP claimed *in general* is the substitution not admissible.

We can evalute these expressions using integration by parts to better see the difference. With $u=\frac{\ln x}{1-x}$ and $dv=\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)dx$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1-x)+C_1
\end{align*}
On the other hand with $u=\frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}$ and $dv=\operatorname{Li}_2(x)dx$ we obtain for the substituted integral (3)
\begin{align*}
-\int\frac{\ln (1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)+C_2\tag{4}
\end{align*}
with $C_1, C_2$ constants of integration.

Later on when Tunk Fey needs to determine a constant of integration he evaluates the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{H}_nx^n}{n^3}$ at $x=1$. Evaluating the subexpressions at $x=1$ above give

\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1-x)\right|_{x=1}&=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(0)=0\\
\left.\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)\right|_{x=1}&=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1)=\frac{\pi^4}{72}
\end{align*}
The   difference of    the    integration    constants $\Delta=\frac{\pi^4}{72}$ has negative consequences when we look at the final calculation at the end.

With this incorrectly substituted expression (3) Tunk Fey obtains from (2)

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nx^n}{n^3}&=\zeta(3)\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx\\
> &\qquad+\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\\
> &\qquad-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x+\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx
> \end{align*}

The next step is to combine $\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}\ dx$ and $\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx$ with the help of the *Euler's reflection formula*
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln x\ln(1-x)
\end{align*}

> He obtains
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nx^n}{n^3}&=\zeta(3)\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx
> +\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x\\
> &\qquad+\int\frac{\ln(1-x)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\ln x\ln(1-x)\right)}{x}\ dx\\
> &=\zeta(3)\ln(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x\\
> &\qquad-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\int\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx\\
> &=\zeta(3)\ln(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x\\
> &\qquad-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

The next step is to simplify $\color{red}{\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}$. He continues with (question marks emphasis mine)

> (Tunk Fey:) Setting $x\mapsto1-x$ and using the identity $H_{n+1}-H_n=\frac1{n+1}$, the red integral becomes
> \begin{align*}
> \color{red}{\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx}&\stackrel{???}{=}-\int\frac{\ln (1-x)\ln^2 x}{1-x}\ dx\\
> &=\ldots\\
> &=\frac12\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)-2\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\right]\\
> &\qquad+2\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^3}-\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\right]\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

The  substitution (???) right at the beginning is not justified and not admissible. It will also have some influence when calculating the integration constant at the end.

---

> **OP: Why do we omit the constant of integration in the following step? We should add the constant since it will affect the summation.**

OPs argument is valid. The RHS of (6) should have a constant of integration included. But note that Tunk Fey introduces  in the following step this constant and this aspect is no longer a potential problem.

> Continuing with (5) and substituting (6) Tunk Fey obtains
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nx^n}{n^3}
> &=\zeta(3)\ln(x)-\frac{1}{2}
> \left(\frac12\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)-2\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\right]\right.\\
> &\quad\left.+2\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^3}-\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\right]\right)
> +\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\\
> &=\zeta(3)\ln(x)-\frac{1}{4}
> \ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)+\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\ln x\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\\
> &\quad-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^3}+2\operatorname{Li}_4(x)
> -\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}
> It  follows
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nx^n}{n^3}
> &=\frac{1}{2}\zeta(3)\ln(x)-\frac{1}{8}
> \ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln x\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\\
> &\qquad+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)
> -\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+C\\
> \end{align*}

In the last step Tunk Fey determines the integration constant $C$ by setting $x=1$ in (7) and using the *[known value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305476/a-series-involving-the-harmonic-numbers-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn3?lq=1)*  of
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^3}=\frac{\pi^4}{72}
\end{align*}
and some special values of Polygamma functions (maybe with some help of Wolfram Alpha).

> (Tunk Fey:) Setting $x=1$ to obtain the constant of integration,
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3}&=\operatorname{Li}_4(1)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\operatorname{Li}_2(1)+C\\
> \frac{\pi^4}{72}&=\frac{\pi^4}{90}-\frac{\pi^4}{72}+C\\
> C&=\frac{\pi^4}{60}.
> \end{align*}
> Thus
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_nx^n}{n^3}=&\frac12\zeta(3)\ln x-\frac18\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n} x^{n}}{n^2}-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\right]\\&+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)\ln x+\frac{\pi^4}{60}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

---

> **OP: Is the identity even true, since putting $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ gives a [numerically different result][2] than [the correct result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E4%2F(720)+%2B+ln%5E4(2)%2F(24)+-+ln(2)%2F(8)+zeta(3)+%2B+Polylog(4,1%2F2)), as pointed out by the user [@Super Abound](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/140590/superabound) in the comments of that answer.**

Again OPs doubt is reasonable, since due to the inadmissible substitutions in (3) and (6)  the integration constant $C=\frac{\pi^4}{60}$ is not correct.

Evaluating the result (8) at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ gives (with some help of Wolfram Alpha)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^32^n}&\stackrel{???}{=}-\frac{1}{8}\ln 2\zeta{3}+\frac{1}{24}\left(\ln 2\right)^4+\frac{7\pi^4}{720}+
\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&\stackrel{.}{=}1.36998
\end{align*}
The        RHS giving $1.36998$ is also challenged by user @SuperAbound in the comment section of Tunk Fey's answer.

> The correct answer seems to be provided by @Cleo which is
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^32^n}&=-\frac{1}{8}\ln 2\zeta{3}+\frac{1}{24}\left(\ln 2\right)^4+\frac{\pi^4}{720}+
> \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
> &\stackrel{.}{=}0.55824
> \end{align*}
> The          numerical  value is also stated in the answer by @MhenniBenghorbal.

The difference of the two answers $\Delta=\frac{\pi^4}{120}$ seems to be a result due to the erroneously performed substitutions.

---

**Epilogue:**

The answer of Tunk Fey is full of nice ideas and it's worth that somebody provides a correct proof based upon his calculations. Avoiding the substitutions the main challenge seems to be (see (5)) obtaining an appropriate representation of
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx
\end{align*}
Wolfram Alpha provides a solution for this integral but it looks much too cumbersome.

Comment: (+1) Thanks a lot! Very nicely written answer and you addressed all my doubts.

Comment: @IshanSingh: You're welcome! Many thanks for your nice comment. :-)

Comment: @IshanSingh: I've added an *[answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909228/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn32n/1855171#1855171)* which avoids the above mentioned problems. Regards,

Comment: Beautiful... I always had doubt with his solution and that substitution he made does not make any sense.

Comment: @AliShadhar: Many thanks, Ali. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The sum in question has a closed form in terms of polylogarithms.  The proof is complicated, and I don't intend to reproduce it as I derived it some 15 years ago, and polylogs are not a primary interest now.  You can always differentiate both sides and use polylog IDs in Lewin.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{y^k}{k^3}H_k=\zeta(4)+2 Li_4(y)-Li_4(1-y)+Li_4(-y/(1-y))+\\
\frac{1}{2} \log(1-y) \Big( \zeta(3) – Li_3(y)+Li_3(1-y)+Li_3(-y/(1-y)) \Big)
+ \\\frac{1}{12}\log^3(1-y)\log(y) -\frac{1}{24}\log^4(1-y)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{H_{n} \over n^{3}}\,x^{n} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\,x^{n}\
\overbrace{\bracks{%
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{t}t^{n - 1}\,\dd t}}^{\ds{1 \over n^{3}}}\ =\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{t}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
H_{n}\pars{xt}^{n}\,{\dd t \over t}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - xt} \over
\pars{1 - xt}t}\,\dd t =
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t/x}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over
\pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t
\\[1cm] & =
-{1 \over 2}\ln^{2}\pars{x}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over
\pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\mc{I}_{1}\pars{x}}}\ +\
\ln\pars{x}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over
\pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\mc{I}_{2}\pars{x}}}
\\[2mm] &
-\,{1 \over 2}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over
\pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t}_{\ds{\mc{I}_{3}\pars{x}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{-\,{1 \over 2}\ln^{2}\pars{x}\mc{I}_{1}\pars{x} +
\ln\pars{x}\mc{I}_{2}\pars{x} - {1 \over 2}\mc{I}_{3}\pars{x}}
\label{0}\tag{0}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{1}\pars{x} =\ ?}$.
\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{1}\pars{x} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over \pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{-\,{1 \over 2}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} - \mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{2}\pars{x} =\ ?}$.
\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{2}\pars{x} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over \pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{1}^{1 - x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> Since
>   $\ds{\int{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t =
> -\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{t} + \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{t}}$ and
>   $\ds{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1} = \zeta\pars{3}}$:

\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{2}\pars{x} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over \pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t =
\bbx{-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 - x} + \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 - x} - \zeta\pars{3}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\mc{I}_{3}\pars{x} =\ ?}$.
\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{3}\pars{x} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over \pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t =
\bbox[10px,#eef]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}} +
\bbox[10px,#fee]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}}
\end{align}
The $\color{#00f}{\mbox{first integral}}$ is evaluated as follows:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#eef]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}} =
-\int_{0}^{x}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} + 2\int_{0}^{x}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{t}\ln\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} +
2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}
-2\int_{0}^{x}\mrm{Li}_{4}'\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[10px,border:2px groove #00f]{-\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} + 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x} -
2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x}}
\label{3a}\tag{3a}
\end{align}
Hereafter, I'll evaluate the $\color{#f00}{\mbox{second integral}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#fee]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{x}{-3\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} +
3\ln\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t\ +\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{\int_{1}^{1 - x}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\ln^{2}\pars{t}\,\dd t}}
\label{3b}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
The last integral evaluation is similar to \eqref{2}. Namely,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t & =
-2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1 - x} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x}
\\[2mm] & +
2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\ + \
\underbrace{\qquad{\pi^{4} \over 45}\qquad}_{\ds{2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1} =
2\,\zeta\pars{4}}}
\label{3c}\tag{3c}
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x}{-3\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} +
3\ln\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{3}\pars{t/\bracks{1 - t}} - \ln^{3}\pars{t} +
\ln^{3}\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{x}\ln^{3}\pars{t \over 1 - t}\,{\dd t \over 1 - t} -
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{3}\pars{t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t +
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{3}\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{x}\ln^{3}\pars{t \over 1 - t}\,{\dd t \over 1 - t} +
\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{3}\pars{x} +
3\int_{0}^{x}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{t}\,\dd t -
{1 \over 4}\,\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x}
\end{align}
The second integral was already evaluated in \eqref{3a}. Namely,
$$
\int_{0}^{x}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{t}\,\dd t =
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} - 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x} +
2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x}
$$
such that
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x}{-3\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} +
3\ln\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{x}\ln^{3}\pars{t \over 1 - t}\,{\dd t \over 1 - t} +
\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{3}\pars{x} +
3\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} -
6\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}
\\[2mm] &\
+ 6\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x} - {1 \over 4}\,\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x}
\label{3d}\tag{3d}
\end{align}
In the remaining integral I'll make the change $\ds{{t \over 1 - t} \mapsto t}$
such that
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x}\ln^{3}\pars{t \over 1 - t}\,{\dd t \over 1 - t} =
-\int_{0}^{x/\pars{x - 1}}{\ln^{3}\pars{-t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{1 - {x \over x - 1}}\ln\pars{x \over 1 - x} +
3\int_{0}^{x/\pars{x - 1}}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{-t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} + \ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} +
3\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln^{2}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
\\[2mm] &\
-6\int_{0}^{x/\pars{x - 1}}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{t}\ln\pars{-t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} + \ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} +
3\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln^{2}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
\\[2mm] &\
-6\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln\pars{x \over 1 - x} +
6\int_{0}^{x/\pars{x - 1}}\mrm{Li}_{4}'\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} + \ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} +
3\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln^{2}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
\\[2mm] &\
-6\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln\pars{x \over 1 - x} +
6\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
\end{align}
By replacing this result in \eqref{3d}, I found
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{x}{-3\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} +
3\ln\pars{t}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - t}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} + \ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} +
3\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln^{2}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
\\[2mm] &\
-6\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln\pars{x \over 1 - x} +
6\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
 +
\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{3}\pars{x} +
3\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x}
\\[2mm] &\
-6\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}
+ 6\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x} - {1 \over 4}\,\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x}
\end{align}
such that \eqref{3b} becomes
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#fee]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} - {1 \over 3}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln^{2}\pars{x \over 1 - x}
\\[2mm] &\
+ 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln\pars{x \over 1 - x} -
2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x \over 1 - x} -
{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{3}\pars{x} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x}
\\[2mm] &\
+ 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}
- 2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x} + {1 \over 12}\,\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x}
-2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1 - x} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x}
\\[2mm] & +
2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 - x} + {\pi^{4} \over 45}
\label{3e}\tag{3e}
\end{align}
With \eqref{3a} and \eqref{3e}:
\begin{align}
\mc{I}_{3}\pars{x} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{x}{\ln^{2}\pars{t}\ln\pars{1 - t} \over \pars{1 - t}t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\begin{array}{|l|}\hline \mbox{}\\
\ds{-2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{x} + 4\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x}\ln\pars{x} -
4\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x}}
\\[2mm] 
\ds{+ {1 \over 3}\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{x} - {1 \over 3}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln^{2}\pars{x \over 1 - x}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{+ 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x \over x - 1}\ln\pars{x \over 1 - x} -
2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{x \over 1 - x} -
{1 \over 3}\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln^{3}\pars{x}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{+ {1 \over 12}\,\ln^{4}\pars{1 - x}
-2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1 - x} -
\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 - x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{+ 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 - x} + {\pi^{4} \over 45}}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

> The *final result* is given by \eqref{0}, \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} and
>   \eqref{3}.